# Are all real orthogonal matrices $O_n$ and invertible matrices $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ open sets? connected sets?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $n\times n$ real matrix as an element in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ with Euclidean topology.

1. Is $O_n$ open or closed? How about $G_n=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?
2. Is $O_n$ a connected set? How about $G_n$?

---

With question 1.1, I construct a map
$$f:O_n\to \mathbb{R}^{n^2},\\A\mapsto AA^T.$$
$f$ is a continuous map (this is easy to show with matrix norm). Notice that $f$ maps all the orthogonal matrices to $I$, a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ as well as a closed set, the preimage $O_n$ is closed.

For 1.2, the determinant function $\det$ tells that $G_n$ is open by similar reasons with 1.1.

However, I am not sure how to deal with question 2 in a similar manner. It seems that the continuity cannot induce connectivity of preimage. Does it mean that I need some other mappings for question 2? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $O_n$, consider the image under $\det$.

Comment: @AJY $\det$ maps them to $\{\pm 1\}$, so it is not connected. Is this reasoning right?

Comment: Correct. This means $O_n$ has two connected components.

Comment: @AJY Then for $G_n$ it would be similar, as $\det (G_n)=\mathbb{R}-\{0\} $ not is connected! Get it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw., one does not need matrix norm. The coordinate components of $f$ (and $\det$) are polynomial expressions in the coordinates

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. This is a more precise observation. Thanks!